# MySQL many-to-many table relationship with three entities

Tags: mysql, database

Three record tables:

accounts, users and roles

Users can belong to multiple accounts with different roles.

Currently, I have a join table:

accounts_users_roles (With three columns for FK relationships to each tables PK.)

Primary key in this table is (accounts.id,users.id,roles.id)

Is there a more efficient way to establish these relationships?

EDIT: Roles and users may be shared by accounts. Accounts assign user roles.

Comment: What is inefficient in your approach?  How do intend to query this data?

Comment: It depends on the business rules you're modeling. Right now you have a 3-way many-to-many. A user can have many accounts, but an account can have many users. Is this what you want? Similarly, you have a role belonging to a paritcular combination of account and user, which I imagine is not correct. Does a role belong to an account or a user? Can multiple accounts/users have the same role?

Comment: @Schwern Users can belong to multiple business accounts. Each business account assigns the user roles. Accounts have multiple users.

Comment: @user1730452 So User1 can have Account1 and Account2. Account1 can have User1 and User2? Each account can have multiple roles, and a user gets their roles through their accounts? Can a role have multiple accounts? A concrete example showing how these are all connected would help.

Comment: @PM77-1, Queries are mainly by accounts (companies) for their users. I say that, but the system queries the user RBAC for the user session.

Comment: @Schwern Good question. Roles and users are shared by accounts. Does that help?

Comment: @user1730452 It's unclear what that means. Can a role be part of multiple accounts?

Comment: @Schwern Yes accounts share system provided roles. When an account adds a user they assign the roles. That user can belong to another account with different roles that were selected from the same role pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, I understand the business rules to be that a user has many roles for many accounts. Joe is the manager for the ConHugeCo account, and also does customer service for EvilInc. Kathy is president of the Hair Club and is also a client.

Yes, a single table is appropriate.

```
account     user     role
ConHugeCo   Joe      Manager
EvilInc     Joe      CustomerService
HairClub    Kathy    President
HairClub    Kathy    Client

create table accounts_roles_users (
  account_id integer not null references accounts(id) on delete cascade,
  role_id integer not null references roles(id) on delete cascade,
  user_id integer not null references users(id) on delete cascade,

  unique(account_id, role_id, user_id)
);
```

[`on delete cascade`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) ensures when a user or account or role is deleted, their join table entry is deleted. And we avoid duplicate entries by [making the user/account/role combination unique](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/).

You may wish to allow the user_id to be null to indicate an unfilled role.

Comment: How would one determine the user roles for a particular account?

Comment: @user1730452 I think I've misunderstood your setup. Users have roles for accounts? Joe is Manager for the ConHugeCo account?

Comment: Yes! You have the business logic correct. "You may wish to allow the user_id to be null to indicate an unfilled role". All three columns are required since all users must have roles when added to the account. Right now I have the columns combined as a PK. Why do you suggest a Unique key?

Comment: @user1730452 I don't see a need for a primary key on such a simple join table. If it needed one, it would be a simple auto-incrementing integer. Small, efficient, easy to refer to, won't change. But I don't see any harm, a primary key enforces uniqueness.